# How to set Badge value of Tabbar customizable view controller?

Tags: swift, tabbar

I want to set the badge value of Tabbar item which is available in "More" Tabbar item .
I have 7 tabbar in tabbarcontroller so i want to set the badge value of 6th tabbar item.

For Ex :

```
tabbarController.tabBar.items?[6].badgeValue = "1"
```

In my iPhone only 4 tabs are visible right now.

But when i set `items?[6].badgevalue` then app crash at run time. so how can i set badge value ?

Comment: Please show us your code snippet.

Comment: self.tabBarController.tabBar.items![6].badgeValue = "6"

Comment: @HardikBhalgamiya can u be more specific what u want to achieve

Comment: I want to set badge value In Tabbarcontroller if item is more then 5 then it's native functionality it show only 4 item and remaining item display in "more" Tabicon when press. i want to set badge value on remaining items .

Answer (score 0):

If you SubClass UITabBarController and set this subclass in interface builder and you use 
`tabBar.items?[6].badgeValue = "7"` it should not crash.

The question is where you are referencing tabbarController from. Is it hooked up at the moment you call it? Is it possible that it is nil?

These are all questions that would be easier to answer if you posted the bit of code. However my guess is that you're not calling it from a place that can access it at the time of calling